# How to set "ORDER BY" for two cases?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

In mysql, I need to set the "ORDER BY" for two cases: name or mod_1, depending on what the user selected in a combobox. My query is:

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(IF(mod = 1, 1, 0)) AS mod_1,
    SUM(IF(mod = 2, 1, 0)) AS mod_2,
    SUM(IF(mod = 3, 1, 0)) AS mod_3
FROM
    DW_RM_Log
WHERE
    ...
ORDER BY
    name (or mod_1 DESC)
```

Is it possible to do this in mysql or I need to code it in php? Or both?

Comment: Just generate a proper query in php and run

Comment: It works, but I don't want two queries for each case...

Comment: have one query and append it with a proper `ORDER BY` in runtime

Comment: 90% of the query wont change just append the  `order by` clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bored enough to do this for you:

```
$q = "SELECT
    name,
    SUM(IF(mod = 1, 1, 0)) AS mod_1,
    SUM(IF(mod = 2, 1, 0)) AS mod_2,
    SUM(IF(mod = 3, 1, 0)) AS mod_3
FROM
    DW_RM_Log
WHERE
    ...
ORDER BY ";

if ($x) {
    $q .= "name DESC";
} else {
    $q .= "mod_1 DESC";
}
 //run $q!
```